# Getting all output from terminal in C

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I am currently working on a ssh program and I want to be able to have full control over the terminal via networking. My question is, if I send a command to the server to run in the terminal, how do I get the output that the terminal prints? I have seen many posts saying to use the `popen()` command but from what I have tried I can't change directories and do other commands using this, only simple things such as `ls`. Is there any other way to get output from terminal besides sending it to a file like `command > filetoholdcommand`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I am currently working on a ssh program` - You mean you're writing a SSH client? Or are you using an existing SSH client to execute commands on a remote machine? The 2nd option doesn't keep your login session open, so CWD is reset to your HOMEDIR for every new connection.

Comment: @jweyrich I am writing the client and the server. Can you clarify as to what you mean when saying it doesn't keep my login session open?

Comment: good luck getting it right implementing SSH.

Comment: I was using SSH as an example, basically I will just send commands to the server, it will execute the commands, and send back the output from the terminal, etc.

Comment: @HurricaneChris: I meant that if you use the OpenSSH client, like `ssh [-t] <host> 'commands'`, it will establish a new connection, execute the commands, and close the connection. In other words, if you changed the directory, and later issued a `ls`, it will not list files from the directory you're expecting - because the session is lost when the connection is closed.

Comment: @jweyrich Oh gotcha, well I am not using the OpenSSH client, so the connection will remain open on both sides unless I specifically close it.

Comment: @HurricaneChris: Ok. So I think you should provide more details on how you're establishing your connection, and how you're executing commands.

Comment: @jweyrich Communication is established with common tcp/ip networking with Berkeley Sockets, but what I want to do is send commands to the server for execution and get output from the server back. For example, if I send `ls` to the server it will send back the list of files, but I want to be able to do more things such as `cd` and manipulate files like a command line on client side.

Comment: @HurricaneChris: That can be a very complex task. You need to handle various terminal control sequences and modes. Assuming a VT100 compatible terminal, you can read more in the [VT100 User Guide](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug). Chapter 3 contains a lot of details about modes, cursor position, scrolling, etc. I hope that does not discourage you though.

Comment: @jweyrich Thanks for the link, and I will try my best to not get discouraged, perhaps i could sell this one day :D.

Comment: You might want to peruse some telnet source code....

Answer (score 3):

I would put this as a comment, but I dont have enough rep as I'm new. cd is a built in shell command so you want to use system(). But cd will have no effect on your process (you have to use chdir(), for that),so what you really want to do is start a shell as a subprocess via fork/exec, connect pipes to it stdin and stdout,then pipe it commands for the duration of the user session or connection.

Following code give the general idea. Basic, and flawed - use select() not usleep() for one.

```
int argc2;
printf( "Server started - %d\n", getpid() );
char buf[1024] = {0};
int pid;
int pipe_fd_1[2];
int pipe_fd_2[2];
pipe( pipe_fd_1 );
pipe( pipe_fd_2 );

switch ( pid = fork() ) 
{
case -1:
    exit(1);
case 0: /* child */
    close(pipe_fd_1[1]);
    close(pipe_fd_2[0]);
    dup2( pipe_fd_1[0], STDIN_FILENO );
    dup2( pipe_fd_2[1], STDOUT_FILENO );
    execlp("/bin/bash", "bash", NULL);
default: /* parent */
    close(pipe_fd_1[0]);
    close(pipe_fd_2[1]);
    fcntl(pipe_fd_2[0], F_SETFL, fcntl(pipe_fd_2[0], F_GETFL, NULL ) | O_NONBLOCK );
    while(true)
    {
      int r = 0;
      printf( "Enter cmd:\n" );
      r = read( STDIN_FILENO, &buf, 1024 );
      if( r > 1 )
      {
        buf[r] = '\0';
        write(pipe_fd_1[1], &buf, r);
      }
      usleep(100000);
      while( ( r = read( pipe_fd_2[0], &buf, 1024 ) ) > 0 )
      {
        buf[r-1] = '\0';
        printf("%s", buf );
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying that up for me, but how would you start a shell as a subprocess?

Comment: See basic example added in edit. Should go in a main() with the appropriate headers of course, but could not paste the entire C file and get it to format properly...

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly! Now the problem is implementing this with the networking portion.

Answer (score 1):

You want the "[popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)" function.  Here's an example of running the command `ls /etc` and outputting to the console.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

  FILE *fp;
  int status;
  char path[1035];

  /* Open the command for reading. */
  fp = popen("/bin/ls /etc/", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to run command\n" );
    exit;
  }

  /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
  while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", path);
  }

  /* close */
  pclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know how to use `popen()` and how to send the `ls` command, but it can't change directories or anything more useful from what I have tried.

Comment: `fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp)` should be `fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp)` - stdlib functions are well-designed.

Comment: @HurricaneChris Your error might be with the SSH part of the program then.

Comment: @syb0rg I tried using a program similar to the one above except replacing `/bin/ls /etc/` with a variable from the user, in this case `cd Documents/` and it returns `/bin/sh: Documents/: is a directory`

Comment: Is `Documents/` in the current directory?

Comment: Call chdir before calling popen? or call a script on the ssh server that does everything you need and popen that.

Comment: @syb0rg Yes `Documents/` is in current directory. I want to send commands to server and get output from terminal back on client side. Such as having a linux terminal, but on the client side.

Comment: Perhaps you could do what Matt said, and just run a script on the server and send the output back.

Comment: @syb0rg That is the problem I am facing, I can send the command and what not, but I don't know how to get all of the output from terminal even when changing directories and what not. `ls` works fine, but `cat > file` and other commands won't.

Comment: You got the output `/bin/sh: Documents/: is a directory` from the terminal, right?

Comment: Yes I did, but I can't move to the directory along with I can't do other commands such as `rm file`

Comment: Then I don't think your problem is with getting output from the terminal.  I would ask another more specific question to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @syb0rg Well i guess my question is, what is the best way to have full control over the terminal and commands and get all output back, because when using `popen()` I can't `rm` files and other things for some reason.

Comment: I meant to Stack Overflow, not me specifically.

Comment: Haha my bad, I appreciate your help though.